# T4 Template File doesn't compile VS2019 V16.4.5

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, t4

I have a T4 Template file in my project and I use it everyday but after upgrade into 16.4.5 version I'm getting this error when I Run Custom Code:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Running transformation:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error
>   HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.Utilities.Exceptions.ThrowEFail()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.FileCodeModel.GetDocument()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.FileCodeModel.GetSyntaxTree()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.FileCodeModel..ctor(CodeModelState
>   state, Object parent, DocumentId documentId, ITextManagerAdapter
>   textManagerAdapter)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.CodeModelProjectCache.GetOrCreateFileCodeModel(String
>   filePath, Object parent)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.ProjectCodeModel.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.IProjectCodeModel.GetOrCreateFileCodeModel(String
>   filePath, Object parent)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp.ProjectSystemShim.CSharpProjectShim.CreateFileCodeModel(String
>   fileName, Object parent, FileCodeModel& ppFileCodeModel)    at
>   EnvDTE.ProjectItem.get_FileCodeModel()    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingA79231EE6EFCFD9A9F7580CC47D516BF0E336BDEE9E25B0EE85E3BDE9AA5F22021A94E93566B81968DF5D01D105C4011D1E60A396DC22B9D70AA7669950944CC.GeneratedTextTransformation.d__7.MoveNext()
>   in XXX\SecurityKeys.tt:line 134    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingA79231EE6EFCFD9A9F7580CC47D516BF0E336BDEE9E25B0EE85E3BDE9AA5F22021A94E93566B81968DF5D01D105C4011D1E60A396DC22B9D70AA7669950944CC.GeneratedTextTransformation.d__6.MoveNext()
>   in XXX\SecurityKeys.tt:line 127    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingA79231EE6EFCFD9A9F7580CC47D516BF0E336BDEE9E25B0EE85E3BDE9AA5F22021A94E93566B81968DF5D01D105C4011D1E60A396DC22B9D70AA7669950944CC.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
>   in XXX\SecurityKeys.tt:line 48    MYPROJECT   XXX\SecurityKeys.tt 134

I tested the same file in my colleague's workstation with previous version of VS and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

just exclude all project files and folders then include them again! it works